# NSArray not loading UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have the following NSArray

```
(
"<Events:pxhQQ5wqBz:(null)> {\n    EventName = \"Volunteer Fiar\";\n    School = \"<School:9CbVOFj1be>\";\n    SchoolName = \"Quinnipiac University\";\n}",
"<Events:x06pKsCIxm:(null)> {\n    EventName = \"QU vs Yale\";\n    School = \"<School:9CbVOFj1be>\";\n    SchoolName = \"Quinnipiac University\";\n}",
"<Events:Cc3KQLY9MR:(null)> {\n    EventName = \"Bobcat Madness\";\n    School = \"<School:9CbVOFj1be>\";\n    SchoolName = \"Quinnipiac University\";\n}"
)
```

I am trying to add an item from that array into a label in my UITableView and it seems to crash my application. Any ideas why? I keep getting the following crash:

```
-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10d923bc0
```

Here is my code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.eventArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   cell.textLabel.text = [self.eventArray valueForKey:@"EventName"];
}
```

To clarify some, the amount of rows that are supposed to be returned is correct. I just cannot seem to get EventName in the textLabel object.

Comment: Your call to `valueForKey:@"EventName"` is actually returning another array of all of the event names.

Comment: isn't it should be `[[self.eventArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"EventName"];`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an object of type `Event` stored in the eventArray, and that Event object has a property `EventName`, you need to get the event associated with that row *first*, and then you can set event's name on the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   // do all your normal cell creation/reuse stuff here...

   Event *eventForRow = self.eventArray[indexPath.row];
   cell.textLabel.text = eventForRow.EventName;

   return cell;
}
```